# XMLHttpRequest.responseType "arraybuffer" encoding implementation

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer

I'm hooking the xhr object on some third party js and on each call i'm sending the url to retrieve via an open websocket connection and actually fetch the resource on the server side and return the response .
everything is working as it should except when the responseType is set to "arraybuffer" than apparently i mess something up because the code doesn't work as it should , i tried using this implementation : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String  . but the arraybuffer returned length is "967818" and if i use the native xhr object and set the responseType to "arraybuffer" the returned length "508728" so it's a lot smaller, anyway there is a solution for this? because i need to encode the response to an arraybuffer and via the method above the third party js just keep trying to request the same resource (ts file) probably because it can't decode it.
ideas?

EDIT:
some additional data:
the Content-Type for the resource is  video/mp2t , the Content-Length is 508728 .